# libGDX FileHandle file not found on ios

Tags: ios, libgdx, file-handling

I have `bin` folder in my android `assets` folder in which I store json file for my default values for my game.

I read this file using

```
FileHandle gameDataFile = Gdx.files.local("assets/bin/levels_data");
```

and this work perfect on android phones. Today I try to export my game for ios and I get this error:

```
 File not found: assets/bin/levels_data (Local)
```

I tried to remove `assets` from path but I get same error again (`File not found: bin/levels_data (Local)`)

Can some one tell me how to solve this, how to read from iso, file that is located in assets folder?

I want to mentioned that asset loader loads all other filed(images, textures, sounds...) that are located in `assets` folder on ios . Problem is when I try to read file with `Gdx.files.local` but only on ios device ( simulator for now)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What does `Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath()` return, when running on iOS? I guess problem is that `android/assets` folder is not considered as local storage on iOS. I couldn't find what is local storage path for iOS. This is a quote from libgdx wiki: "Local files are stored relative to the application's root or working directory on desktops and relative to the internal (private) storage of the application on Android. Note that Local and internal are mostly the same on the desktop." But there is nothing about iOS local storage.

Answer (score 0):

To access internal package files (like assets on Android), you have to use internal (not local) file handle. Try this:

```
FileHandle gameDataFile = Gdx.files.internal("bin/levels_data");
```